# Insert a whole linked list into other at given position

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

So I have a homework problem, which ask me to insert a linked list in to other linked list at the given position pos.

When pos == 0, all the elements of the 'other' list will be placed before the (original) elements of this list if pos >= length(), (i.e. if x is greater than the length of this list), then all the elements of the 'other' list are appended to this list. After insertion all the elements in 'other' list gets removed

here is my function below

```
void LList::splice(Node* head, LList& other, int pos) {
    if (head == nullptr) {
        head = other.head;
        other.head = nullptr;
            return;
    }
    else if (pos > this->length()) {
        if (head->next == nullptr) {
            head->next = other.head;
            other.head = nullptr;
        }
        splice(head->next, other, pos);
    }
    else if (pos == 1) {
        Node* temp = head->next;
        head->next = other.head;
        while (other.head->next != nullptr) {
            other.head = other.head->next;
        }
        other.head->next = temp;
        other.head = nullptr;
        return;
    }
    else {
        splice(head->next, other, pos--);
    }
}
```

for example:
list = [ 11 22 66 77 ] and other = [ 33 44 55 ]

`list.splice(other, 2)` should give me a list = [ 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 ]. However it is still returning the original one. Can someone help me with this?

```
class  LList {
public:
    void splice(LList& other, int pos);
private:
    struct Node {
        int item;
        Node* next;
    };
    void splice(Node* head, LList& other, int pos);
    Node* head;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: There should be no need to pass `head` into a member function. `head` is a member variable. It's already known.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any point to recursing, either. You should walk through your logic and draw some pictures to get a better idea of what you want to happen and what is happening.

Comment: but its a homework requirement to do everything recursively

Comment: Yuck. If you are allowed to steal the guts out of `other`, all you really need to do is split the list at `pos` (you can recurse your way to it, I guess). Set pos's `next` to the head of `other` and then recurse to the end of the combined list and stick on what used to be pos's `next`. The key to this is have a function that recurses until it finds a node at `pos` or if pos is impossible, (-1 for example)  recures to the end , and returns a reference to the node found.